# How to set up Apache with Tomcat on CentOS

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, centos

I currently running a Grails app in a Tomcat container on a CentOS box and I have images taking up to 6 seconds to load on my website. They are roughly 500KB each.

I've been told a way to improve resources loading is to proxy to Apache Tomcat with Apache HTTP Server with an AJP connector. Then I can pick up my resources (e.g. Images) with Apache HTTP Server and proxy the other requests through to Apache Tomcat running on another port.

What is the most simplest way of setting up a Grails application with Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat on CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty comprehensive set of instructions for setting up tomcat & apache here:

http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/277036/Three-ways-to-integrate-Tomcat-and-Apache-for-best-performance-and-features

Once you've setup tomcat, you just need to drop your grails application WAR file in the tomcat webapps directory and start it up using the regular startup.sh script.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions I used to setup on Ubuntu. Maybe you can go off this to get started.

Tomcat6 configuration:  Enable the AJP connector in the /etc/tomcat6/server.xml file like this:

```
Connector port="8009" enableLookups="false"
redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3"
```

Restart the Tomcat server.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

Apache2 configuration: Enable the proxy and proxy_ajp modules

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_ajp
```

Add new virtual host to the sites-available folder

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite.com

    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ajp.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ajp.log combined

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009
```

Enable virtual host site and restart Apache2

```
$ sudo a2ensite threebaysover.com
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you fail to set the ServerName then on an Apache restart you will see the following warning:

apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's
fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

To stop the warning and set the ServerName, add the following to the apache2.conf:

```
ServerName demo
```

Instructions from: http://www.code-republic.com/?p=1